# Cleanest way to globally override a Console style

Tags: symfony, console, symfony4

> **tl;dr:** I want to change an output formatter style across my entire Console application without having to modify every command. How can I make a single set of changes that take effect globally?

I want to globally change the error output formatter style in [my Symfony 4 Console application](https://github.com/acquia/orca). [As per the documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/4.4/console/style.html#defining-your-own-styles), it's easy to do so in an ad hoc fashion per command, e.g.:

```
public function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output): int {
  $output->getFormatter()->setStyle('error', new OutputFormatterStyle('red'));
}
```

But I don't want to add needless boilerplate to all my commands--especially not with a `new` operator. For maintainability and testability, I prefer to override and inject my dependencies via the service container. I tried to do this by overriding the output formatter:

MyOutputFormatter.php

```php
use Symfony\Component\Console\Formatter\OutputFormatter;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Formatter\OutputFormatterStyle;

class MyOutputFormatter extends OutputFormatter {

  public function __construct($decorated = FALSE, array $styles = []) {
    // I've tried it this way:
    $styles['error'] = new OutputFormatterStyle('red');

    parent::__construct($decorated, $styles);

    // I've tried it this way:
    $this->setStyle('error', new OutputFormatterStyle('red'));

    // And I've tried it this way:
    $this->getStyle('error')->setForeground('red');
    $this->getStyle('error')->setBackground();
  }

}
```

services.yml:

```yaml
Symfony\Component\Console\Formatter\OutputFormatterInterface:
  alias: My\Console\Formatter\OutputFormatter
```

MyCommand.php

```
use Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;

class MyCommand extends Command {

  public function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output) {
    $output->writeln("<error>I'm an error.</error>");
  }

}
```

But I must be doing something wrong, because although my class definitely gets injected and interpreted, whether I try to override an existing style or create a new one, it has no effect: I expect my custom style to be used (red foreground with no background), the default style is used instead (white foreground with a red background).

Can someone correct my misunderstanding or suggest a better way? Thanks!!

Comment: if it still doesn't work if you assign it afterwards, I would probably add some logging to `setStyle`, maybe it gets overridden more often ... ? just noticed, that the styles given to the constructor are actually applied afterwards. so it should work either way ... How are you certain that your output formatter is the active one?

Comment: @Jakumi, no, my style doesn't appear to get applied at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it! It turned out to be very simple: The `Application` class has a `configureIO()` method for precisely this purpose. This is all I had to do in the end:

`Application.php`

```php
class Application extends \Symfony\Component\Console\Application
{
    protected function configureIO(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output): void
    {
        $output->getFormatter()->setStyle('error', new OutputFormatterStyle('red'));
    }
}
```

Note that this solution assumes that you're using your own `Application` class in your front script, e.g.:

`bin/my-command.php`

```php
$application = new \My\Application();

$application->add(new MyCommand());
// etc.

$application->run();
```